# getting error in Yii Login with Eauth extension

Tags: php, yii

I am using yii eauth extension to log in . I have imported both eauth and lightopenid exactly the way it is supposed to be.
The problem is that I am getting an error on loid.

> Missing argument 1 for LightOpenID::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\yumtest\protected\extensions\lightopenid\loid.php on line 34 and defined

What do I need to do to overcome this error?

Comment: Why don't you use default yii login(without any extra extensions)?

Comment: i want to create login with facebook,google and twitter etc

Comment: Your question can only be answered if we see what is on line 34...

Comment: seems like a bug of the plugin, you're using a newer version of the extension.

Comment: will you provide me a good plugin link?